# MySQL Combining One to Many into One Row

Tags: mysql, join

I have a one to many table setup. What I want to do is join the tables but instead of having it return multiple rows showing the different combinations, I want it to return 1 row that has 3 fields, one for each row from the many table.

```
Data:
dataID (primary key),
other data,
other data,
other data

Codes:
codeID,
dataID (foreign key),
codeValue
```

Expected output:
dataID, codeValue1, codeValue2, codeValue3

Comment: What determines what value from `codes` should be in the first, second, or third field?  Does it matter? Or does `codeID` somehow determine what slot the value goes into?

Comment: The order doesn't matter much, however there is a field called codeSequence that would be able to determine which would go where.

Comment: Technically this is would be a pivot table, which MySQL doesn't directly support. There's ugly workarounds, but the easiest one is to simply do the transformation in your client, rather than hacking up queries that'll break if someone blinks at them within 50 miles.

Answer (score 1):

```
select concat(DataID,',',CodeValues) ExpectedOutput from
(
    select A.dataID,GROUP_CONCAT(B.codeValue ORDER BY B.codeID) CodeValues
    from (select dataID from Data) A
    inner join Codes B using (dataID) group by A.dataID
) AA;
```

Make sure you have this compound index

```
ALTER TABLE Codes ADD INDEX data_code_ndx (dataID,codeID,codeValue);
```